# Telegram API + Perl + sendDocument

Tags: telegram-bot, perl

Доброго времени суток!
 Использую WWW::Telegram::BotAPI. Пытаюсь отправить pdf-файл с помощью sendDocument:

```
$tm="sendDocument";
$api->$tm ({
   chat_id => $u->{message}{chat}{id},
   document => "https://cloud.mail.ru/public/.."
});
```

Вываливаются ошибки:

> ERROR: code 400: Bad Request: wrong file identifier/HTTP URL specified at /usr/local/share/perl5/WWW/Telegram/BotAPI.pm line 208
>   WWW::Telegram::BotAPI::api_request(undef, undef, 'HASH(0x9d78040)') called at
>   /usr/local/share/perl5/WWW/Telegram/BotAPI.pm line 76
>           WWW::Telegram::BotAPI::AUTOLOAD('WWW::Telegram::BotAPI=HASH(0x99f02f0)',
>   'HASH(0x9d78040)') called at ./sp****ia.pl line 62

Причем фото шлет норм.
Кто-нибудь сталкивался/решал данную проблему?

Comment: тут же явно написано: "wrong file identifier". читай https://core.telegram.org/bots/api/#sending-files

Comment: Спасибо! Но это я читал. В отлупе написано "wrong file identifier/HTTP URL specified". / --, как я понимаю,  или.
file identifier -- это про file_id, которого у меня нет. У меня есть URL.

Comment: UPD: с фото случаются проблемы такие же проблемы

Answer (score -2):

https://github.com/Robertof/perl-www-telegram-botapi гласит:

> $api->sendPhoto ({
>       chat_id => 123456,
>       photo   => {
>           file => '/home/me/cool_pic.png'
>       },
>       caption => 'Look at my cool photo!' });

по url до Телеграмма (вскоре запрещенный мессенджер в РФ) не доходит (невсегда, но бывает, пробовал с разных ресурсов всякие картинки подпихивать) по каким-то не понятным причинам. С pdf так же вышел из ситуации.